# Dynamic Query Parameters in FastAPI

Tags: fastapi

I have a requirement to send dynamic query parameters to REST web service GET method [as shown below].

host:port/app?field1=value1&&field2=value2&....

The consumer can send parameters up to fieldn and valuen. Each field maps to the value.

With this type of requirement, I can't code a finite set of QueryParams on the server side method.

I'm using python and fastapi

Thanks.

Comment: What's your question? And: What do you have up to now?

Comment: My question is how do I take an arbitrary amount of parameters in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea to pass an arbitrary number of query parameters to the endpoint is to use the `Request` class provided by FastAPI. It gives a dict with all the query parameters you passed to the endpoint. Write your endpoint like the following:

```
@app.get("/app")
def read(..., request: Request):
    query_parameters_dict = request.query_params
    ...
```

Comment: With the '...' do you mean other parameters? otherwise it's considered an error. Also in this way, Swagger can't add any documentation.

Comment: Yes, I was meaning your other parameters (path parameters, session etc)

Comment: Sorry, but if the query parameters aren't defined a priori, what Swagger UI should show ?